# Not able to access dictionary inside list which is again inside dictionary in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to get value of item `a`
The structure is like

```
${dict1}  Create Dictionary  a=1  b=2
${dict2}  Create Dictionary  x=1  y=2
${list1}  Create List  ${dict1}  ${dict2}
${master_dict}  Create Dictionary  payload=${list1}
```

Now I know, I can use below logic to access items indirectly

```
${dict}  Get From List  &{master_dict}[payload]  0
${item}  Set Variable  &{dict}[a]
```

But I want to know, is there a direct way to access it. I have already tried

```
${item}  Set Variable  &{master_dict.payload[0]}[a]
```

and

```
${item}  Set Variable  @{master_dict.payload[0]}[a]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using robot's [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) you have to remember that what you provide must be valid python. In your case that means that `payload` needs to be `"payload"`, and `a` needs to be `"a"` (or the single-quote equivalent).

If you were doing this in python code, it would look like this:

```
item = master_dict['payload'][0]['a']
```

Therefore, from within robot, everything inside the curly braces needs to look the same. For example:

```
${item}=  set variable  ${master_dict['payload'][0]['a']}
```

You can also treat the value as a dictionary and move the last part outside of the curly braces, in which case you only need quotes inside the curly brace.

```
${item}=  set variable  &{master_dict['payload'][0]}[a]
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan. Changing it to as you said; `&{order_details['payload']['suborders'][0]}[productSubTransactionId]` solved the issue.